# Using MediaPlayer to play a notification beep on Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv

I have some code that plays a small notification beep from an mp3 (included in res/raw) that works fine on regular Android devices (various 2.2 and up), which I am trying to also use on Google TV and it doesn't seem to do anything, no errors, just no sound.

What could I be doing wrong (this has to be something simple that I am missing?).

Here is the basic code I'm using:

```java
private void beep() {
   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
   if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
      try {
         Log.d(App.LOG_TAG, "playing the damn beep ****************");
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
         // tried with and without volume 
         ///mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
         mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
         mediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("beep", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
      }
   } else {
      Log.d(App.LOG_TAG, "could  not gain audio focus");
   }   
}
```

(NOTE: In real life I don't recreate the MediaPlayer and AudioManager every time, but I tried just putting everything in one method for test purposes. This works fine on the regular Android emulator, and on regular Android [phone] devices, but plays no sound on GTV emulator or Logitech Revue -- even though it does get into the MediaPlayer block fine and logs that it's playing the beep.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Notification sound in Settings->Picture & sound ->Notification sounds->Sounds->Default ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, no difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For whatever reason, it looks like the files need to be in ogg format. I tried .mp3, and a few versions of .wav. Even the GTV dev docs (https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats#StandardFormats) say .mp3 is okay.

My HiSense Pulse Google TV only plays the files if they are .ogg files.

This online converter seems to work: http://media.io/